Is there any way to stop a block of code from running once a conditional has been met?
var land = createSprite(200, 200);
land.setAnimation("land");
var space = createSprite(200, 200);
space.setAnimation("space");
var mars = createSprite(200, 200);
mars.setAnimation("mars");
var rocket = createSprite(350, 285);
rocket.setAnimation("up");
var astronaut = createSprite(25, 325);
astronaut.setAnimation("astronaut");
astronaut.width = 75;
astronaut.height = 75;
astronaut.visible = 1;

function draw() {
    mars.setAnimation("mars");
    if (keyDown("d")) {
        astronaut.x = astronaut.x + 3;
    }
    if (keyDown("a")) {
        astronaut.x = astronaut.x - 3;
    }
    if (astronaut.x > 330) {
        mars.setAnimation("space");
        astronaut.visible = 0;
    }
    if (astronaut.visible === 0) {
        astronaut.destroy();
        if (keyDown("a")) {
            rocket.setAnimation("left");
            rocket.x = rocket.x - 3;
        }
        if (keyDown("d")) {
            rocket.setAnimation("right");
            rocket.x = rocket.x + 3;
        }
        if (keyDown("w")) {
            rocket.setAnimation("up");
            rocket.y = rocket.y - 3;
        }
        if (keyDown("s")) {
            rocket.setAnimation("down");
            rocket.y = rocket.y + 3;
        }
    }
    drawSprites();
}

For an engineering project, I need to make a card of sorts. In that card, I want the astronaut to reach an x value, disappear, and set the background to a new sprite. However, once the rocket goes behind the x value, the background is set to the previous sprite.

make good use of else if case

WHat library is this from createSprite()? And what is the effect of lines like land.setAnimation("land");?

This is from the code.org library. The land.setAnimation("land"); I believe is to assign the land sprite variable to a specific animation in the library.

"This is from the code.org library" ... Do you have a link? (to serve as reference for the properties and methods you use)

It's not clear what your question is. You've stated a set of requirements but no problem description

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
